# How are LRU and Clock algorithm different?

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, memory-management, virtual-memory

I am modeling the Gclock-pro buffer replacement algorithm in Linux kernel.

Because there are many existing modeling works on LRU, I am considering adopting LRU model to roughly describe Gclock-pro, if they are similar.

I read some papers and documents looking for their relationship.

- LRU page replacement scheme is hard to implement.
- Second chance algorithm is a good approximation of LRU.
- Clock algorithm is one way to implement Second chance algorithm.
- GClock-pro algorithm is improved version of clock algorithm with additional hands. It approximates Low Inter-reference Recency Set (LIRS) algorithm.
- LIRS outperforms LRU.

I think there is a circular relationship between LRU and GClock-pro. Unfortunately I have no idea where to start.

Can anyone give any intuition on their differences?